# How to make a web input field start shrinking after a certain window width?

Tags: html, css

I have started following tutorials on how to build responsive web pages and I have stumbled onto a problem I want to resolve. When I shrink the width of the browser window, I don't want the form to just go to the next line when it gets near the h1 header, but instead I want the input field to shrink (or at least the whole form). In short, I want the whole #newsletter section to stay on the same line when I resize the window.

```css
/* Global */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button_1 {
  height: 38px;
  background: #e8491d;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: white;
}


/* Newsletter */

#newsletter {
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  background: #35424A;
}

#newsletter h1 {
  float: left;
}

#newsletter form {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#newsletter input[type='email'] {
  padding: 4px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <section id="newsletter">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Subscribe to our newsletter</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email...">
        <button type="submit" class="button_1">Subscribe</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

`Display: inline` does nothing, and I presume I could use media queries, but I don't know what CSS to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`display: flex` for `#newsletter form` and `#newsletter .container` will force them to stay in one line, unless you add `flex-wrap: wrap` property.

If you are new to flexbox I recommend [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

#### Key part

```
#newsletter .container {
  display: flex;
}

#newsletter form {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

#### Snippet

```css
/* Global */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button_1 {
  height: 38px;
  background: #e8491d;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: white;
}


/* Newsletter */

#newsletter {
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  background: #35424A;
}

#newsletter .container {
  display: flex;
}

#newsletter h1 {
  float: left;
}

#newsletter form {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#newsletter input[type='email'] {
  padding: 4px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <section id="newsletter">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Subscribe to our newsletter</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email...">
        <button type="submit" class="button_1">Subscribe</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the initial width of the input bar or button, simply change its width in CSS code.

Here I used CSS Grid. I added 100% width to form, so we can set the width of elements inside the form explicitly which help us to auto-resize items.

```css
/* Global */
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 50%);
}

.button_1 {
    height: 38px;
    background: #e8491d;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Newsletter */
#newsletter {
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    background: #35424A;
}

#newsletter h1 {
    float: left;
}

#newsletter form {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#newsletter input[type='email'] {
    padding: 4px;
    height: 25px;
    width:80%
}

form {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    max-width: 100%;
}

form button {
    flex-shrink: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <section id="newsletter">
        <div class="container">
            
            <h1>Subscribe to our newsletter</h1>
            <form>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email...">
                <button type="submit" class="button_1">Subscribe</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
```